# Update table from webpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using a stored procedure to update a table when the user clicks approve however I get message that it was approved successfully but the table wasn't updated.

Update
I'm now only able to update one item; even I select more than one item it is only updating one.

Stored Procedure

```
Update RequisitionItem
set [status] = 0,
[approve_date] = @approve_date
--[ApprovedBy]=@ApprovedBy
where [status]=-1 and Req_No=@reqNumber and item_no=@item_no
```

Method

```
 public void SetRequisitionStatus0(List <string> reqNumber,List <string> item_no)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "requisition_sp_setstatus0";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@reqNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters.Add("@item_no", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        //command.Parameters.Add("@ApprovedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters.Add("@approve_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

        using (command.Connection = connection)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                 foreach (var item in reqNumbers)
                {
                    command.Parameters["@reqNumber"].Value = item;

                    foreach (var item1 in item_no)
                    {
                        command.Parameters["@item_no"].Value = item1;
                    }

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }

            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the foreach loops are messing you up. The inner loop will loop the entire list (item_no) then go back to the outer loop, then the inner loop will go through the entire list again, always giving you the last item. You need a `for` loop, **something like**

```
for(int i = 0; i < reqNumbers.count; i++)
{
    command.Parameters["@reqNumber"].Value = reqNumbers[i];
    command.Parameters["@item_no"].Value = item_no[i];

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

you don't need to close the connection either - the using statement will close it automatically. and you don't need the final `return`.